# lightning:combobox can we pre-populate the value?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community

Does lightning:combobox allows users to pre-populate values? Also when I'm searching i can't see the values I'm typing. looks like currently it's read only?

Here i could print the value and label but i couldn't show it as selected in the combobox!

Anyone faced the same issue? or any idea?

```
<aura:attribute name="selectedRecord" type="Object" />

value--{!v.selectedRecord.value}
lable--{!v.selectedRecord.label}

        <lightning:combobox aura:id="productDropdown" 
                            name="products" label="Product" required="true"
                            placeholder="{!$Label.c.ips_COMM_Case_OpenNewCase_SelectAProduct}" 
                            value="{!v.selectedRecord}" readonly="true"
                            messageWhenValueMissing="{!$Label.c.ips_COMM_Case_MustGatherFields_RequiredText}"                                
                            onchange="{!c.handleOptionSelected}" 
                            options="{!v.productOptionsAll}"/>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by pre-populate value? And are you saying that when you select an option from the combo box, the selected value does not show in UI?

Comment: lightning:combobox is read only. Can you try putting a string literal for the value attribute? See if v.selectedRecord has a value, display it somewhere. Also, what is in the handleOptionSelected method?